# How to merge two small list in the same nested list in python?

Tags: python, list

I want to merge two small list share same values in the nested list in python as below.

Input:

```
listL = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,2,9,10]]
```

`ListL[0]` and `List[2]` share same values `1` and `2`, so the output should be:

```
listL = [[1,2,3,4,9,10],[5,6,7,8]]
```

The output result `ListL` still need to keep the same name and id as the input.

Comment: What do you call list's *name*?

Comment: You have a list of lists, the inner lists share certain values and you want to merge the inner ones into the same list if they share values? what logic applies if multiple inner lists share values? `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,2,7,8]` ?

Comment: what did you try to solve this puzzle, what does not work with your attempt?

Comment: Please be more clear in your question. Do you want to merge *all* sub-lists that overlap in their members? Is it allowed to build another list that satisfies your requirements then modify `listL` to have the same contents? Also show some of your own attempts on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to extend lists without resorting to sets and removing duplicates in the process while maintaining the list-id() - it is going to be tricky. Modifying parts of an iterable while iterating it leads to disaster, so you would need to somehow remember what to delete while iterating and extending inner lists and then delete afterwards... or copy the correct content data into the original list.

This is one way to do it:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,2,9,10]]

print(id(data),data)

merged = []                 # our list with merged parts from data
alreadyMerged = []          # ref to the part we already merged once and can skip
deletePart = []             # 
for partList in data:       # go over every part list of data
    foundOne = True
    deletePart = [partList] # we will ignore the current one
    if partList in alreadyMerged:  # skip if already processed ealier
        continue
    while foundOne:         # as long as we find other partlists that have any(.)
        for other in data:
            foundOne = False
            if other in alreadyMerged: # skip parts we already merged
                continue
            if other in deletePart:    # skip parts we already visited
                continue  

            if any(x in partList for x in other): # current other has common content?
                foundOne = True
                print("found one:  " , partList, other)
                for oneNum in other:    # add anything that isnt already in
                    if oneNum not in partList:
                        partList.append(oneNum) 
                alreadyMerged.append(other) # remember we used this part list already
                break
        foundOne = False  # we checked all things, skip to next one
    print("out of while:", partList)
    merged.append(partList)

print(merged)

data [:] = merged # this will overwrite the contents of data in place, same id

print(id(data),data)
```

Output:

```
1062059796616 [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 9, 10]]

found one:   [1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 9, 10]
out of while: [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10]
out of while: [5, 6, 7, 8]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

1062059796616 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listL = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[1,2,9,10]]

new_listL = []
for l in listL:
    sl = set(l)
    for nl in new_listL:
        if sl.intersection(nl):
            nl.extend(sl -set((nl))
            break
    else:
        new_listL.append(l.copy())

print (new_listL)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: I think you mean `nl.extend(sl - set(nl))`

Comment: @PatrickArtner. That was due to a silly mistake. Should be fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @ukemi.. yes indeed.. fixed now

Comment: Can `new_listL` still be `listL` with same id?

Comment: you are modifying the iterable you are currently iterating over - do you think thats wise?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes.. I realized that reverted back to my previous answer